# I can't run a ruby file in sublime Text 3

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

When I try to run my file with the "build" option in sublime text it tells me *"building"* and then just stops. I don't get an error message and it doesn't crash, it works fine to edit the code. It just doesn't run it at all. It worked when I didnt use "def" as command but I have to use them for a school project and it doesnt work at all. 
Edit: It does work with def but it doesnt work when I try to get user input.

Comment: Build systems in Sublime can't be interactive unless you do extra work to set it up. If you're using the build system that ships with Sublime, that's why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows OS:

**1. Create launcher batch file C:\Ruby26-x64\RBCMDRUN.BAT**

```
@echo off

TITLE %1
set EXE=%~dp0bin\ruby.exe
set MYARGS=
:NEXTARG
  if "[%~1]" NEQ "[]" (
      IF "[%~1]" EQU "[-PAUSE]" (
        set ALWAYSPAUSE=Y
        shift
        goto NEXTARG
      )
      if "%MYARGS%" EQU "" (
        set MYARGS=%~1
      ) else (
        set MYARGS=%MYARGS% %~1
      )
      rem echo %MYARGS%
      if not "[%~1]"=="[]" (
        shift
        goto NEXTARG
      )
  )

IF "[%MYARGS%]" EQU "[]" (
    ECHO Error: ruby file name is missing
    GOTO PAUSEANDEXIT
)

echo %EXE% %MYARGS%
%EXE% "%MYARGS%"

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Program exited with error %ERRORLEVEL% 
    GOTO PAUSEANDEXIT
)

IF "%ALWAYSPAUSE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO EXIT

:PAUSEANDEXIT
PAUSE
:EXIT
EXIT
```

**2. Add or Modify .sublime-build for Ruby**

Packages/Ruby/Ruby.sublime-build

```
    "cmd": ["start", "C:\\Ruby26-x64\\RBCMDRUN.BAT", "$file", "-PAUSE"],
    "shell": true,
```

Remove "-PAUSE" if you don't need it.

**3. [Optional] Bind a key for running your script**

Preferences - key bindings

`{ "keys": ["f5"], "command": "build"},`